# how to run agent's command line or powershell using azure pipleine?

Tags: windows, automation, azure-devops

is there any way that i can invoke the command line of Azure Deployment agent? The tasks currently available don't invoke the agents' command line, but in fact install their own.

Comment: what do you mean? tasks run on the agent, say powershell task would run on the agent

Comment: but it will not invoke the PS, it will not run interactively.
i have a .bat file, i want to run it on the Agent. When i hit it through Powershell, the bat file runs in the pipeline, but it can't access the agents resources

Comment: well, since this is an automated process - nothing will run interactively. but it will invoke powershell to run it. how do you think it will run powershell script without running powershell?

Comment: yes i know that actually powershell runs, but isn't there any way that i can invoke the bat file and it runs interactively?
any suggestion or idea?

Comment: why? just call the bat file like you normally would. I'm not sure what do you mean by interactively, though

Answer (score 0):

1.Make sure your .bat file itself is free of errors.

2.Use the following command in powershell in your pipeline

```
    Start-Process "<the path of cmd.exe on our host agent>" -ArgumentList "/k <the target .bat file on your host agent>"
```

The function of this command line is to open the cmd on your host agent then run the .bat file. You can refer to this link to learn how does it work

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-6